# adding many elements together in p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

i want to make a textbox and a dropdown list together. when i run code it executes only one(either that textbox or dropdown)

here's my code:

```
let button;
let sel;
let sel2;
var text;
var x = 10;
var y = 230;
var img;

function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, 600);
background(0);

img = loadImage("audi.jpg");

  sel = createSelect();
  sel.position(20, 150);
  sel.option('FERARI');
  sel.option('MERCEDES');
  sel.option('TOYOTA');
  sel.option('AUDI');
  sel.option('BMW');

  sel2 = createSelect();
  sel2.position(300, 150);
  sel2.option('FERARI');
  sel2.option('MERCEDES');
  sel2.option('TOYOTA');
  sel2.option('AUDI');
  sel2.option('BMW');

  button = createButton('COMPARE');
  button.position(550, 150);
  button.mousePressed(display);

  text = createInput();
  text.pos(300, 300);
}

function display() {
  textSize(16);
  fill(255, 215, 0);
  let index = sel.value();
  text(index, 20, 430);

  let number = sel2.value();
  text(number, 300, 430);

  if(sel.value() === 'BMW') {
    text('MILEAGE: 14-20 km/l', 20, 460);

    text('COST: 41.7-48.5 LAKH', 20, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PREMIUM FUEL', 20, 520);
  }

if(sel.value() === 'AUDI') {

  text('MILEAGE:  9 km/l', 20, 460);

  text('COST: 1.345 CORE', 20, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PETROL', 20, 520);
  }

  if(sel.value() === 'FERARI') {
    text('MILEAGE: 9 km/l', 20, 460);

    text('COST: 3.5 CORE', 20, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PETROL', 20, 520);
  }

  if(sel.value() === 'MERCEDES BENZ C CLASS') {
    text('MILEAGE: 10-19 km/l', 20, 460);

    text('COST: 40.9 LAKHS', 20, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: UNLEADED FUEL', 20, 520);
  }

  if(sel.value() === 'TOYOTA') {
    text('MILEAGE: 7-10 km/l', 20, 460);

    text('COST: 28.66-36.88 LAKH', 20, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: MID GRADE GASOLINE', 20, 520);
  }

  if(sel2.value() === 'AUDI') {
  text('MILEAGE:  9 km/l', 300, 460);

  text('COST: 1.345 CORE', 300, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PETROL', 300, 520);
  }

  if(sel2.value() === 'BMW') {
  text('MILEAGE: 14-20 km/l', 300, 460);

  text('COST: 41.7-48.5 LAKH', 300, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PREMIUM FUEL', 300, 520);
  }

  if(sel2.value() === 'TOYOTA') {
  text('MILEAGE: 7-10 km/l', 300, 460);

  text('COST: 28.66-36.88 LAKH', 300, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: MID GRADE GASOLINE', 300, 520);
  }

  if(sel2.value() === 'FERARI') {
  text('MILEAGE: 9 km/l', 300, 460);

  text('COST: 3.5 CORE', 300, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: PETROL', 300, 520);
  }

  if(sel2.value() === 'MERCEDES BENZ C CLASS') {
  text('MILEAGE: 10-19 km/l', 300, 460);

  text('COST: 40.9 LAKHS', 300, 490);

  text('FUEL TYPE: UNLEADED FUEL', 300, 520);
  }
}
```

(don't laugh at the design.)
when i do some arranging, then sometimes the textbox appears and when i click the compare button nothing happens.

pls help and thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

1. You have a variable named `var text`. Because p5.js is already using that name for a function, you have to rename it to something like `var textBox`. (Don't forget to change the lines in your `setup()` as well)
2. `textBox.pos()` is not a valid function. Change it to `textBox.position()`;